# Whether Certificate Manager is required for service "IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA"

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

I am new person in ibm cloud
I need install service "IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA"

For the guide "Getting started with Certificate Manager"
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/certificate-manager?topic=certificate-manager-getting-started

I found "Next steps" (import certificate or order certificate)

Is it needed in installation for "IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA" or can be ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Activity Tracker with LogDNA and Certificate Manager are two different services on IBM Cloud. In the documentation, certificate manager is shown as an example on how to use  pay-as-you-go service. Any lite service you create in you IBM Cloud account triggers an event and can be seen in the activity tracker

> If you have a pay-as-you-go account, you can use Certificate Manager to create an event. If you don't have a pay-as-you-go account, provisioning any of the available lite services triggers an event.

Check the getting started [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-getting-started)

Comment: Yes, i am a pay-as-you-go account, actually, our project in ibm cloud does not have certificate yet, can i not involve certificate manager service in my Activity Tracker with LogDNA? just want to confirm this("Next steps" (import certificate or order certificate)) is required steps or optional?

Comment: please help to check that

Comment: Certificate manager provisioning is an optional step.